# Pattern "allocate memory or use existing data"

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have field
`std::map<std::string, std::map<unsigned int, float>> widths;`

I copy data to widths[key] from another map or insert custom data to widths[key] depending on runtime criteria. However, copying is too slow.
I am going to use pointer to std::map<unsigned int, float> as widths::value. Thus(depending on runtime criteria):

1. Pointer has address of existing map.
2. Allocate memory and write custom data.

Also I need flags to decide if delete widths::value in destructor. Do you know better pattern to resolve this task?

Comment: I think there's not enough stuff described in the question for us to answer. We need more context to tell opinions about ways to solve the problem

Comment: shared_ptr ...?

Comment: `*std::map<unsigned int, float>` is syntactically invalid. The `*` specifier isn't allowed there.

Comment: I think the information you're missing is `std::move` to reassign a map without doing a full copy

Comment: I can`t move it, cause I need to copy it again in the future

Comment: probably some kind of smart ptr, which is set to be deallocated or not during initialization would be a good match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following wrapper is created:

```
class Widths
    {
    public:
        Widths() : widths(new std::map<unsigned int, float>), to_be_deleted(true)
        {
        }

        Widths(const std::map<unsigned int, float> *arg) noexcept : widths(const_cast<std::map<unsigned int, float>*>(arg)),
                                                                    to_be_deleted(false)
        {
        }

        ~Widths() noexcept
        {
            if (to_be_deleted) delete widths;
        }

        Widths(Widths &&arg) : widths(arg.widths), to_be_deleted(arg.to_be_deleted)
        {
            arg.widths = nullptr;
            arg.to_be_deleted = false;
        }

        Widths(const Widths &arg) = delete;
        Widths& operator=(const Widths &arg) = delete;

        const std::map<unsigned int, float>* operator->() const
        {
            return widths;
        }

        std::map<unsigned int, float>* operator->()
        {
            return widths;
        }

    private:
        std::map<unsigned int, float> *widths;
        bool to_be_deleted;
    };
```

`std::map<std::string, std::map<unsigned int, float>> widths;` is changed to
`std::map<std::string, Widths> widths;`

Answer (score 0):

So you want to reference an `std::map<unsigned int, float>` inside another container based on some criteria?

In this case you need a map of pointers, like: `std::map<std::string, std::map<unsigned int, float>*>`. This way you shall be able to do:

```cpp
if(criteria)
    widths[key] = &targetMap;
```

Using `std::map` to sort stuff and then iterate over is not a bad idea, but of course really depends on a real context. By speculating we can only say that is the best method ever and never use something else, which doesn't make sense

Comment: you propose solution which I mentioned in the question. If criteria is not met you need to allocate memory, and delete it in destructor. To decide delete or not you should add flags fields. I feel this solution is not optimal

Comment: You don't need to allocate memory if the criteria is not met. You don't change the map in such a case

Comment: if the criteria is not met I need to write custom data to this map

Comment: Maybe you should use some other pattern. If you want to keep in the map both stuff already made (without copying) and new one, then maybe you shall use multiple maps or make an encapsulating class which has a map pointer and a `bool` for ownership. You can dive into smart pointers too to achieve the task

Comment: Multiple maps is not the best choice, cause I need to check which map to use every time I need width(which is too slow)